# need to get two different config files with different set of variables using same template and playbook Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I want to deploy the code in two systems....

`group_vars/all` has different variables, eg.

```
---
# group variable for webservers
username: abc
```

`hosts` i have windows group and two machine ips..

```
[webservers]
10.0.1.2

[databases]
10.0.1.3
```

`role/tasks/playbook` i have play which will execute on both machines...

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - base
```

**Current:**

- its taking var from all folder and substituting in jinja2 template and running the tasks based on the template info.

**Need:**

- i am in a situation only one user variable like username should be different for two machines.....
  finally i want to run the same playbook and same template with `username=abc` on one machine and `username=xyz` on another machine..

is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Beside `group_vars` there are `host_vars`, where you can define individual variables per host. Everything that is host dependent should be stored there and your username appears to fit there.

For hosts other than those two you can fall back to variables defined in `group_vars` or set a default value in your template:

```
{{ username | default("AxelFoley")}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to set different variables in a number of different places. You should look at [ansible's variable precedence documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

The most common location for connection usernames is directly in the `hosts` file.

```
[webservers]
10.0.1.2      ansible_ssh_user=vagrant

[databases]
10.0.1.3      ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

If your `username` variable is used to configure some service consumer, then you will should set it in `group_vars` or `host_vars`:

```
---
# group variable for webservers
username: abc

---
# host variables for 10.0.1.2
username: xyz
```

or if you need to loop over some application you are deploying, you may do it on a playbook level:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    app1:
      username: abc
  roles:
    - { configure_application, app: app1 }

- hosts: databases
  vars:
    app2:
      username: xyz
  roles:
    - { configure_application, app: app2 }
```